# How do I change field or model attributes of a third-party Django app?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say, I use django.contrib.flatpages, or any other third-party app in my project. I want to change some of this app's model attributes - for example, verbose_name.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is "don't"; use a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) instead.

Answer (score 4):

It depends. If you want to add some new fields, you can create another model with `OneToOneField`. If you want to add some methods, ordering etc., use proxy model. If you want to change some DB restrictions (e.g. `max_length`) you can patch the source code of the app, but think twice before doing that, you should have a really good reason for that.

If you want to change `verbose_name`, you can override `label` in corresponding form field, no change in model needed.